# ASP - EF 6 bind only certain properties of a complex list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have a view that creates one main object (Author) and a list of other objects for it (Books). So the created object can return the books by calling author.Books.ToList() for example.

My problem is that I only want users to be able to set certain attributes of the book (name, date etc.). I do not want them to be able to inject the form with javascript and set the Price of a book.

How do I tell the framework that I want to bind author.Books[all].Name (and date), but want to discard author.Books[all].Price?
I know I could just manually test it in the controller, but I felt like there is a better solution and I just can't quite put my finger on it.

Some code for context:
An inputbox from the View:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The CanBeBorrowed field is required." id="books_0__CanBeBorrowed" name="books[0].CanBeBorrowed" type="checkbox" value="true"`>
```

You can see how adding extra input fields would corrupt the data.
The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Name,Date,Books")]Author author {...}
```

(In my project, I have different classes with the same structure. That is why it looks silly creating all the books when creating the author.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exactly why we need to use ViewModels,

you can just set in ViewModel

```
[Editable(false)]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

and also in your

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([AuthorViewModel authorVm)
{
      var author = _repository.getById(authorVm.Id);
      //update only the fields of author object that user is allowed to   update.
      author.Name = authorVm.Name;
      author.Date = authorVm.Date;
}
```

you can read more about ViewModels and how to use them 
[here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-3) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc)

Comment: Very good point, I completely overlooked this, shows I am still inexperienced. Thank you for your accurate answer.